# Can we pass and over ride the values of django built_in method paremeters?

Tags: python, django, request

I am using a django built in method

> **password_reset**

which is in

> **django.contrib.auth.views**

, Now I wanna override some values for it like **domain_override** and wanna pass its value through my project view.?

First if all is it possible to override its variable values and pass through them from  your project only , and if yes then How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this but you will need to set up your own view which wraps the auth view meaning that you will have to use a different Url:

```
# in urls.py
url(r'^custom-reset/$', 'myapp.views.custom_password_reset', name='custom_password_reset'),

# in views.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset
def custom_password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do your custom processing of the args and kwargs
    return password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs)
```